# The Discord.js command I wrote does not work

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a Discord bot. Sorry for my bad English.

```js
client.on("message", (msg) => {
    if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "sec Bombacı Mülayim") {
        const toplu = member.guild.channels.cache.find((channel) => channel.name === "toplu-alan");
        toplu.send(`${member} Bombacı Mülayim liked you!`);
    }
});
```

I tried this but when I type "!sec Bombacı Mulayim" nothing happens.I have a channel called "toplu -alan" and "Bombacı Mulayim liked you!" I want the message to send into toplu-alan channel

What should I do? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `toLowerCase()` will make your message content all lowercase so will never match a string that contains uppercase letters ( i.e. "`Bombacı Mülayim `")

Answer (score 0):

`msg.content.toLowerCase()` gives you the text of the message, all in lowercase. So your `!sec Bombacı Mülayim` becomes `!sec bombacı mülayim` when you run `.toLowerCase()`

Since LHS is `!sec bombacı mülayim` and you are checking for `!sec Bombacı Mülayim`, it is giving false as the value, and the code in the If statement is not being answered.

So what you will want do to is changing `prefix + "sec Bombacı Mülayim"` to `prefix + "sec bombacı mülayim"`

```js
if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "sec mombacı mülayim") {
        const toplu = member.guild.channels.cache.find((channel) => channel.name === "toplu-alan");
        toplu.send(`${member} Bombacı Mülayim liked you!`);
    }
```